# handling multiple http call and multiple response

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, promise

I have an object with multiple key value pair and each key value pair need to send as a request and obviously I will have multiple response with some success and some of them as error. Now how to handle them as I have to handle partial success and failure case:

```
requestParams = {0:'value1',1:'value2',2:'value3'}
```

Now each of the value inside `requestParams` need to send a http request and respective response need to handle properly.

I want to

```
for(i=0;i<requestParams.length;i++){
     http.get(url,requestParams[i]).then(resolve,reject)
```

and for both success and reject some alert need to display so how can I handle that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to process a set of promises. The problem is a single failure will cause the `Promise.all` to fail. You can place a `catch()` on the individual promises from `http.get()` and return something into the stream. Since `catch()` returns a fresh non-rejected promise, `Promise.all` doesn't know there was a failure. You can then filter on that to find individual errors.

For example here's a fake `http.get` that fails once:

```js
// Faked HTTP object
let http = {
  get(url) { // will fail for 'value2'
    return url == 'value2' ? Promise.reject("some error for: " + url) : Promise.resolve("some value for: " + url)
  }
}

let arr = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
let promises = arr.map(item =>
  http.get(item)
  .catch(e => "ERROR: " + e) // catch error here, returning a value or error to be processed later
)
Promise.all(promises).then(console.log)
```

Comment: More detailed explanation of this solution can be read in this article [Handling Multiple JavaScript Promises Even if Some Fail](http://adampaxton.com/handling-multiple-javascript-promises-even-if-some-fail/)